# Need help with a PMF example

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, sampling, random-variable

Was reading through my lecture slides and I saw this question
[image]

I am not sure what or how the prof approached this problem after step 6.

It'd be greatly appreciated if anyone can tell me what's going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `12` in your sixth arrow should this be `1/2`? If this is a typo (either in your slides or this post)  then the rest of the problem seems straightforward,  multiply by 2 to get $2y(x)=y(x+1) +y(x-1)$ then $2y(x) = y(x) + y(x)$ and rearrange to get the 7th arrow. Then the problem is a matter of fitting an affine function to 2 points.

Comment: yeah, the prof had a typo in his slides which confused me a lot! thanks